# Identifier wchar_t is undefined

Tags: c, compiler-errors, wchar-t

I am trying to build an open-source project and I found that multiple of

```
identifier wchar_t is undefined error
```

I understand the definition for these intrinsic types comes from the compiler and I am getting for other types but not sure why it is falling apart for wchar_t specifically?
I am suspecting since I am using **Visual Studio 2017 - Clang with Microsoft CodeGen (v141_clang_c2)** as a toolset I am suspecting this could be just as simple as turning the right flag on.

[image]

Comment: have you tried `#include <wchar.h>`

Comment: `wchar_t` is a keyword and a built-in type in C++, but in C it's a typedef defined in both `<stddef.h>` and `<wchar.h>`. Which open source project are you building?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I am trying to build : tpm2-tss

Comment: To be clear I am getting all these errors in UCRT files like, stdlib.h, vcruntime_string.h, corecrt.h etc

Comment: click on "Character set" and select "Unicode"

Answer (score 0):

I added these two lines and it fixed the issue,

```
#undef _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
#include<stddef.h>
```

I am however not sure if this is the optimal change.

So this change is after learning what @keith told me that wchat_t needs to be added for C. Investigated further to understand the compiler level behavior and flags available.
To know why I added the undef of macro please read the below link,

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-wchar-t-wchar-t-is-native-type?view=vs-2019
- https://github.com/microsoft/clang-1/blob/master/test/Driver/cl-zc.cpp

In short,

```
// RUN: %clang_cl /c -### /Zc:wchar_t -- %s 2>&1 | FileCheck -check-prefix=WCHAR_T-ON %s
// WCHAR_T-ON-NOT: argument unused during compilation
// RUN: %clang_cl /c -### /Zc:wchar_t- -- %s 2>&1 | FileCheck -check-prefix=WCHAR_T-OFF %s
// WCHAR_T-OFF: argument unused during compilation
```